# VSCode deletes `\` on save from my regex pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, visual-studio-code

I am trying to write the line:

`const reg = new RegExp('\.js$');`

but my VSCode deletes the `\` from my regex on save.  Is this a setting, or some issue with a plugin?  Searched online, but wasn't finding any relevant answers.

For reference, plugins installed are:
- Angular v5 Snippets
- Beautify
- CodeMetrics
- Debugger for Chrome
- EditorConfig for VSCode
- npm
- npm Intellisense
- Prettier
- TSLint
- vscode-icons

Comment: @kshetline is correct, when using the constructor form of regexp creation, special characters must be preceded by \.  For the record when I paste your code into a js file and save nothing happens.  I do not have beautify, tslint or prettier extensions so perhaps it is one of them?

Comment: Apologies for my delay!  Just getting back to this issue.  Thank you very much for your response!  Looks like ```\\``` is the way to go.  THANK YOU @kshetline and @wp78de!

Comment: @nyc_arts Unfortunately, you have picked an answer that rendered your question as a duplicate while your original question, why the `\\` in your regex gets deleted on saving in VS Code, is related to the duplicate question but not the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether this will fix your problem or not, I'm not sure, but that regex should be:

```
const reg = new RegExp('\\.js$');
```

Since you're doing the regex as a string, you need to double your backslashes to represent a single backslash.

Or you could do:

```
const reg = /\.js$/;
```

It could be that VSCode is deleting the backslash the way you originally wrote this because it's an invalid escape.

Answer (score 6):

The offender is **Prettier**. If `formatOnSave` is activated in the editor/user settings

```
// Set the default
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
// Enable per-language
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```

it will remove `\` in strings if it is not part of a valid escape sequence.
A valid escape sequence like `\\` or `\n` is not affected. So, this is actually in your best interest.

Comment: This is the correct answer! Or at least it is for me, and is a known prettier issue. 

prettier doesn't allow "\" in strings, and will try to delete them. I'm still trying to find a way to prevent prettier from doing that. @kshetline's answer are both good work arounds.. ish. 

My problem is I want to concat a couple regex but am not able as prettier is so aggressively formatting.

Comment: This isn't a satisfactory solution. Auto formatters are in the best interest of developers, particularly ones working as a part of teams, to ensure code is aligning with established code styles. If a formatter is breaking legitimate code, the solution shouldn't be to disable the formatter.

Comment: @Abion47 I do not disagree. However, I did not suggest turning off Prettier, I just pointed out where this was coming from (according to my observation). Also, this answer was given about four years ago. I am kinda surprised this is still an issue. I guess the maintainers decided to not fix this for some reason. *shrug*